# In R Replace Columns values But here has:Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, ,... replacement has one more rows, than data has

Tags: r

I'm new to R and  I tried to do a simple replacement on some values in one column in data frame.

But I always has error shows:

*Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , 9, value = c("Harrisburg PA", "Wilmington DE",  : 
  replacement has 275055 rows, data has 275054*

I read in data use read.csv and use replace on column

*plant[,9]<- replace( plant[,9], "New River Plant VA", "Wytheville VA" )*

Can anyone provide some suggestions? Thanks

Comment: It is difficult to answer without a reproducible example. Try `replace(plant[,9], plant[,9] == "New River Plant VA", "Wytheville VA" )`

Comment: @RonakShah  Thanks, your code works but It keeps printing out the result and I want to replace the value and store in its original column.                       So I tried _plant$col[plant$col == "New River Plant VA" ] <- "Wytheville VA"_

Comment: You need to assign it to the original object. Try `plant$col <- replace(plant$col, plant$col == "New River Plant VA", "Wytheville VA" )`. The one which you tried should also work.